# Vue JS middleware not being triggered before page created

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm currently using Nuxt running in mode `spa`

**nuxt.config.js**

```
mode: 'spa',
router: {
  middleware: 'check-auth'
}
```

then on my **middleware/check-auth**

I'm checking if the the `auth` key is existing from the localStorage then user will be redirected to root `/` otherwise redirect to `/login`

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  if (process.client) {
     if (localStorage.getItem('auth')) {
       console.log('authenticated');
       return redirect('/'); // authenticated, redirect to root
     } else {
       console.log('not authenticated');
       return redirect('/login'); // redirect to /login
     }
  }
}
```

on my **index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1> This is Authenticated Page </h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   created() {
      axios.get('/users')
        .then(response => {
           commit('SET_USERS', response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
           console.log(error)
        });
   }
 }
</script>
```

But whenever I load first time the page `localhost:3000` it's triggering the API request first from the created lifecycle. It should go to `/login`

Comment: Have you checked your local storage if the `auth` object is present before running the application?

Comment: @varit05 I checked there's no auth object present in localStorage. I put console.log from the check-auth middleware and I keep getting 'not authenticated' multiple times

Comment: I suspect, `redirect` is not working from `vuex`. you probably need to do the routing part on the component.

Comment: That shouldnt happen. Can u create a reproduction on codesandbox or giuthub repo?